# Want to track the route of the user's movement

Tags: iphone, ios, mapkit, core-location

Want to point car / bike on the route of the user's movement, in the map using mapkit and core location. How it can be possible ? Is it possible through finding the degree of direction of google map ? If yes, then what is the mathematical formula for that ?

I have tried course property for CLLocation but gives -1 value all the time which indicates invalid direction.

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[map dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }
    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Bike.png"];
    annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);

    return annotationView;
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
        return;
    if  (!newLocation)
        return;

    currentLocation = newLocation;
    previousLocation = oldLocation;
    if(currentLocation != nil)
    {
        if (myAnnotation)
        {
            [self.myMapView removeAnnotation:myAnnotation];
        }
        CLLocationCoordinate2D location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentLocation.coordinate.longitude);
        myAnnotation = [[MyAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinates:location title:@"Current Location" subTitle:nil];
        [self.myMapView addAnnotation:myAnnotation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried!

Comment: I want to pass dynamic direction to this function : annotationView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45); 

but unable to find it.

Comment: Can i provide you reference application on App Store? If you have iPhone then install UBER application to your device and you can check it the functionality.

Comment: Can you help in this, Martin ?

Answer (score -1):

I worked on a similar pet project called "JogBuddy". It is not perfect but you can surely check it out:

https://github.com/azamsharp/JogBuddy

Comment: Thank you, azamsharp. I will check it.

Comment: Your application shows dot for location tracking, and i need custom image like bike / car which rotate on degree of direction as per route of google maps. Can you help regarding that ?